# Add unit test paths to Codeception

Tags: codeception

I have started to create unit tests for small components and added them to a Tests subdirectory within the component directory - so everything is together. No functional or acceptance tests are needed for these simple small components.

But I have not found out how to tell Codeception to run all tests in a directory - I am looking for a similar method like in the PHPUnit config file, where I can just tell PHPUnit to go through all PHP files in a directory (`<directory>src/*/*/*/Tests</directory>` in PHPUnit XML config).

Also, there does not seem to be a reference for possible configuration options in Codeception - so it is really hard to find more advanced configuration options such as these. Or have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

http://codeception.com/docs/08-Customization#One-Runner-for-Multiple-Applications

In your case it would be:

```
include:
  - src/*/*/*
```

But you will have to create a codeception.yml and at least one test suite for each component.

Look at https://github.com/Codeception/symfony-demo/blob/2.2/codeception.yml and https://github.com/Codeception/symfony-demo/tree/2.2/src/AppBundle for an example.

Comment: I read that - and did it for a bundle. But this is really cumbersome if you try to separate different functionality and components, because I will have more Codeception files and actually a lot of added complexity because of Codeception instead of just writing some simple tests (I would already have at least 8 codeception "folders" right now - and I am only starting out to do some sensible functionality splitting so I can reuse components). But I almost suspected that I will need to stick to PHPUnit for most testing, it just seems odd that Codeception makes this so difficult.